# Sort Order of a Lookup Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I am trying to sort my lookup column based on a column called sortby.  I've tried an few of the suggestions, but just can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I have tried and it doesn't sort by the sortby columns:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" 
$().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({ //This is the function that does the sorting.
relationshipList: "Code", //This is the name of the lookup field in the form.
relationshipListColumn: "Title", //This is the original column name from the lookup list as SharePoint knows it.
relationshipListSortColumn: "Sortby"
columnName: "Code", //This is the column name in the lookup list as it shows up.
CAMLQuery: "<Neq><FieldRef Name="Title"/><Value Type="Text"></Value></Neq>", //This is the CAML Query if you want to select a specific set of items from the list. In this example it doesn't select items where the Title column is null. Note, the Title column is the original column name.
debug: true
});
</script>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks
Kim

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write double quote within the double quote. Please replace this line as following  -

```
CAMLQuery: "<Neq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'></Value></Neq>"
```

Also Closing tag is missing in this line after "javascript" - please check --

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
```

I have added the above mentioned points in below code. Please Use it -

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $().SPServices.SPFilterDropdown({ //This is the function that does the sorting.
        relationshipList: "Code", //This is the name of the lookup field in the form.
        relationshipListColumn: "Title", //This is the original column name from the lookup list as SharePoint knows it.
        relationshipListSortColumn: "Sortby"
        columnName: "Code", //This is the column name in the lookup list as it shows up.
        CAMLQuery: "<Neq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'></Value></Neq>", //This is the CAML Query if you want to select a specific set of items from the list. In this example it doesn't select items where the Title column is null. Note, the Title column is the original column name.
        debug: true
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I've been trying so many different way to get this to work, I guess I missed those quotes in one of my many iterations.  But sad to say, it still doesn't work.  Is it even possible in SharePoint 2013 online to sort the lookup column?  I've seen remarks that it is not possible.